# Unable to print to windows print server via Samba

Tags: freebsd, samba, printing

I have setup my Canon laser printer (shared name `canonMF4820d`) on my windows notebook (hostname `Yoga`).

And I have my Freebsd server (hostname `Fruitfly`) installed with CUPS and SAMBA and Samba-smb-backend.

At the FreeBSD server, I run the following command to check the status of my Samba setup for the printing purpose.

```
$ smbclient -L localhost -N
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[HOME] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.25]
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 3.6.25)
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[HOME] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.25]
    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    FRUITFLY             Samba 3.6.25
    YOGA                 
    Workgroup            Master
    ---------               -------
    HOME                 FRUITFLY
```

I did a test print with the following

```
$ echo -en "\r" | smbclient "//yoga/canonMF4820d" -c "print -" -N -U jus%hello
Domain=[YOGA] OS=[Windows 8.1 9600] Server=[Windows 8.1 6.3]
putting file - as stdin-1367 (0.1 kb/s) (average 0.1 kb/s)
```

And on the windows machine, I could see the queue pile up with print jobs if I unplug the usb cable. Once I plug back the cable, the print job will just disappear.

My original assumption is that, as long there is a correct printer driver installed on the windows machine, the  print job would be taken care of by the windows machine.

It seems that my original assumption is flawed.

I hope that someone could enlighten me on this and would appreciate much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you need to install a Driver for your Printer on the FreeBSD machine.

There are CUPS drivers available on the CANON website.

There are people who do hacks to print without a driver (google turns up this http://justin.yackoski.name/winp/ ).

But when there is a PPD file available i suggest to install the PPD file into cups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But wouldn't the print job that being sent to the windows machine has been taken of by the windows printer driver?  Please advise ..thanks.

Comment: Asfar as i know, the answer is no